# How to make panel heading 'fixed' at the top in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to have the panel heading 'fixed' at the top. I tried:

```
.panel-heading {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 99999;
    top: 0;
}
```

It works perfectly for anything below 768px but for anything above it goes way out of range. Any ideas as to why this happens?

```css
.glyphicon-user {
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #3399ff;
    margin-left: 15px;
}

.panel-heading {
 position: fixed;
 width: 100%;
 z-index: 99999;
 top: 0;
}

.panel-heading h1 {
 padding-bottom: 0.65em;
 color: #3399ff;
 font-weight: bold;
}

.panel-body {
 padding: 0;
}

.col-xs-12 {
 padding-left: 0;
 padding-right: 0;
}

.chats {
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.chats li {
 border-bottom: 2px solid #eee;
}

.chats a {
 display: block;
 color: #000;
 text-decoration: none;
 height: 85px;
 padding: 15px 0;
}

.chats a:hover,
.chats a:hover .glyphicon-user,
.chats a:hover .text-muted {
 background-color: #3399ff;
 color: white;
}

.chats .sender {
 margin-left: 10px;
}

.chats .timestamp {
 margin-right: 15px;
}

.chats .chat-sample {
 clear: right;
 margin-left: 50px;
 padding-top: 5px;
 margin-right: 15px;
}

.chats li:last-child {
 border-bottom: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class='container'>
  <div class='row'>
   <div class='col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-centered'>
    <div class='panel panel-default'>
     <div class='panel-heading'>
      <div class='btn-group pull-left'>
       <div class='dropdown'>
        <button class='btn btn-default btn-xs dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' type='button'>
         <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-cog'</span>
        </button>
        <ul class='dropdown-menu'>
         <li><a href='#'>Delete All Chats</a></li>
         <li><a href='#'>Log Out</a></li>
        </ul>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class='btn-group pull-right'>
       <div class='dropdown'>
        <button class='btn btn-default btn-xs dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' type='button'>
         <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></span>
        </button>
        <ul class='dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right'>
         <li><a href='#'>New Chat</a></li>
        </ul>
       </div>
      </div>
      <h1 class='panel-title text-center'>FunChat</h1>
     </div>
     <div class='panel-body'>
      <ul class='chats'>
       <li>
        <a href=''>
         <div class='chat-img pull-left'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-user'></span></div>
         <div class='sender pull-left'><strong>John Appleseed</strong></div>
         <div class='timestamp text-muted pull-right'><small><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-time'></span> Thursday</small></div>
         <p class='chat-sample text-muted'>What time is it?</p>
        </a>
       </li>
       <li>
        <a href=''>
         <div class='chat-img pull-left'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-user'></span></div>
         <div class='sender pull-left'><strong>Verizon Wireless</strong></div>
         <div class='timestamp text-muted pull-right'><small><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-time'></span> Thursday</small></div>
         <p class='chat-sample text-muted'>Your bill is due on 12/12/2012. Please pay before the due date to avoid service interuption. ...</p>
        </a>
       </li>
       <li>
        <a href=''>
         <div class='chat-img pull-left'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-user'></span></div>
         <div class='sender pull-left'><strong>Sergey Brin</strong></div>
         <div class='timestamp text-muted pull-right'><small><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-time'></span> Thursday</small></div>
         <p class='chat-sample text-muted'>Come down to the Googleplex for an interview. We would like to talk to you about some exciti...</p>
        </a>
       </li>
       <li>
        <a href=''>
         <div class='chat-img pull-left'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-user'></span></div>
         <div class='sender pull-left'><strong>John Appleseed</strong></div>
         <div class='timestamp text-muted pull-right'><small><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-time'></span> Thursday</small></div>
         <p class='chat-sample text-muted'>What time is it?</p>
        </a>
       </li>
       <li>
        <a href=''>
         <div class='chat-img pull-left'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-user'></span></div>
         <div class='sender pull-left'><strong>Verizon Wireless</strong></div>
         <div class='timestamp text-muted pull-right'><small><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-time'></span> Thursday</small></div>
         <p class='chat-sample text-muted'>Your bill is due on 12/12/2012. Please pay before the due date to avoid service interuption. ...</p>
        </a>
       </li>
       <li>
        <a href=''>
         <div class='chat-img pull-left'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-user'></span></div>
         <div class='sender pull-left'><strong>Sergey Brin</strong></div>
         <div class='timestamp text-muted pull-right'><small><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-time'></span> Thursday</small></div>
         <p class='chat-sample text-muted'>Come down to the Googleplex for an interview. We would like to talk to you about some exciti...</p>
        </a>
       </li>
       <li>
        <a href=''>
         <div class='chat-img pull-left'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-user'></span></div>
         <div class='sender pull-left'><strong>John Appleseed</strong></div>
         <div class='timestamp text-muted pull-right'><small><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-time'></span> Thursday</small></div>
         <p class='chat-sample text-muted'>What time is it?</p>
        </a>
       </li>
       <li>
        <a href=''>
         <div class='chat-img pull-left'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-user'></span></div>
         <div class='sender pull-left'><strong>Verizon Wireless</strong></div>
         <div class='timestamp text-muted pull-right'><small><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-time'></span> Thursday</small></div>
         <p class='chat-sample text-muted'>Your bill is due on 12/12/2012. Please pay before the due date to avoid service interuption. ...</p>
        </a>
       </li>
       <li>
        <a href=''>
         <div class='chat-img pull-left'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-user'></span></div>
         <div class='sender pull-left'><strong>Sergey Brin</strong></div>
         <div class='timestamp text-muted pull-right'><small><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-time'></span> Thursday</small></div>
         <p class='chat-sample text-muted'>Come down to the Googleplex for an interview. We would like to talk to you about some exciti...</p>
        </a>
       </li>
       <li>
        <a href=''>
         <div class='chat-img pull-left'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-user'></span></div>
         <div class='sender pull-left'><strong>John Appleseed</strong></div>
         <div class='timestamp text-muted pull-right'><small><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-time'></span> Thursday</small></div>
         <p class='chat-sample text-muted'>What time is it?</p>
        </a>
       </li>
       <li>
        <a href=''>
         <div class='chat-img pull-left'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-user'></span></div>
         <div class='sender pull-left'><strong>Verizon Wireless</strong></div>
         <div class='timestamp text-muted pull-right'><small><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-time'></span> Thursday</small></div>
         <p class='chat-sample text-muted'>Your bill is due on 12/12/2012. Please pay before the due date to avoid service interuption. ...</p>
        </a>
       </li>
       <li>
        <a href=''>
         <div class='chat-img pull-left'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-user'></span></div>
         <div class='sender pull-left'><strong>Sergey Brin</strong></div>
         <div class='timestamp text-muted pull-right'><small><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-time'></span> Thursday</small></div>
         <p class='chat-sample text-muted'>Come down to the Googleplex for an interview. We would like to talk to you about some exciti...</p>
        </a>
       </li>
      </ul>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div><!--end column-->
  </div><!--end row 1-->
</div><!--end container-->
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change The CSS for `.panel-heading` from:

```
.panel-heading {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 99999;
    top: 0;
}
```

to this:

```
.panel-heading {
    position: sticky;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 99999;
    top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Works in Chrome! But in safari, aka iphone it does not.

Comment: Never mind, had to use the `-webkit-` prefix. All good thanks!